# Getting rid of ;; in OCaml toplevel

Tags: ocaml

I like [Try Ocaml](http://try.ocamlpro.com)'s toplevel behavior: `;;` is added implicitly when I press `Enter`, and I'm able to use `Shift-Enter` for multiline editing.

Is this possible to get the same feature in standard toplevel or `utop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently. You could imagine implementing this feature as a patch on top (no pun intended) of [utop](https://github.com/diml/utop).